# Apache mod_rewrite for domain name

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having issues figuring out how to use mod rewrite for a domain name.  I think it has to do with the domain extension but not sure.

```
Input: domain.com/google.com
Callback: domain.com/index.php?website=google.com

RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?website=$1
```

Comment: I'm confused as to how this is off topic when it's writing code for htaccess file and PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(.*)` will match *anything*, so it doesn't really matter that you're attempting to match a domain name. Rather, the problem looks to be the presence of the trailing slash `/` which is *not* present in your input. Just remove it and use `^(.*)$`. It is also recommended to add the `[L]` flag.

```
RewriteEngine On
# Avoid rewrite loops on real files like index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?website=$1 [L]
```

If you need to optionally include the trailing slash, add it with a `?` to match zero or one `/` before the end of the input string.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?website=$1 [L]
```